# How to draw this tree?? (maybe hard)

Tags: tikz-trees, trees

[image]

I want to draw the tree like this, but it's arrow not direct to just down, and I don't know how to draw the 'box' and tint the boxs and words.

Comment: Are you the same user as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/440229?

Comment: Oh, I'm a collegue of that user. I was asked to write the question from her but now she is joining and asking.

Comment: Can we perhaps close this question as a duplicate of that then?

Comment: Sure. Sorry for duplicating. But please 'don't' close the other question.

Comment: Of course not, no reason to. (You were actually first, so in that sense the other one is a duplicate of this, but the other one had a code example, so is a better start.) Edit: actually, I can't vote to close because the other one doesn't have an answer yet.