# From tree, I cannot make arrows from each node and give the color for each floor and give a layer to that

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees, tikz-node

I want to draw a tree like the below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[article]
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=2cm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=1.7cm},
]
\node {$f$}
child {node {$|f \ast \psi_{\lambda_i}|$  }}
child {node {} }
child {node {}  }
child {node {$|f \ast \psi_{\lambda_1}|$}
child {node {$||f \ast \psi_{\lambda_1}| \ast \psi_{\lambda_j}|$}}
child {node {}}
child {node {}}
child {node {$||f \ast \psi_{\lambda_1}| \ast \psi_{\lambda_2}|$}}
child {node {}}
child {node {}}}
child {node {}}
child {node {}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried like this.

[image]

First of all, I cannot make arrows from each node.
and how can I give the color like the first image.
Also, how can I make the block or grouping or make an layer to distinguish each group as I grouped in the first image..

Thanks.

Comment: Please can you make your code into something compilable?

Comment: It isn't really a tree, though part of it is. I guess I might draw it as a tree if it is really an annotated tree, just to keep the structure. (I'm not clear whether that is what it is or not.)

Comment: Oh I edited it into compilable. I have no idea it is tree or not. Actually I'm so dumb to use tex..

Comment: Not dumb at all. I meant 'tree' in the graph-theory sense i.e. single route. It is a tree if the labels are not counted. Otherwise, it is hard to make it out to be a tree.

Comment: 'Single route' -> 'single root' ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I probably wouldn't draw that as a tree. In the code below each box is a single node, with a label defined with the `quotes` library syntax to add the expressions placed on the left side of the boxes. The syntax of the `calc` library, which lets you calculate the coordinate that is a fractional distance between two other coordinates, is used to draw the arrows.

Note that I have not written the same expressions as in your image, I'll leave that to you.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  quotes,
  positioning,
  calc
}

\newcommand\spaceddots{\hspace{1.5cm}\dots\hspace{1.5cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  r/.style={red!80!blue},
  b/.style={red!20!blue!70},
  red box with label/.style={
    r,
    draw,
    "#1"{left,r}
  },
  blue box with label/.style={
    b,
    draw,
    "#1"{left,b}
  },
  myarrow/.style={thick,-stealth}
]

\node [red box with label={$S_0\dots$}] (r1) {$f\ast\phi_{1}$};

\node [below=of r1,
       xshift=1cm,
       red box with label={$S_1\dots$},
       "80:$f(x)$"{name=fx}
  ] (r2) {
  $|f\ast\psi_{1}|\ast\phi_1$
  \spaceddots
  $|f\ast\psi_{1}|\ast\phi_1$};

\node [below=1.5cm of r2.south west,
       red box with label={$S_2\dots$}
  ] (r3) {
  $|f\ast\psi_{1}|\ast\phi_1$
  \spaceddots
  $|f\ast\psi_{1}|\ast\phi_1$};


\node [above=5pt of r3.20,
       anchor=south west,
       blue box with label={$U_0\dots$}
  ] (b1) {
  $|f\ast\psi_{1}|\ast\phi_1$
  \spaceddots
  $|f\ast\psi_{1}|\ast\phi_1$};

\node [below=of r3.-20,
       blue box with label={$U_1\dots$}
  ] (b2) {
  $|f\ast\psi_{1}|\ast\phi_1$
  \spaceddots
  $|f\ast\psi_{1}|\ast\phi_1$};


\draw [myarrow,r] (fx.south) -- (r1);

\foreach [count=\i] \x in {0.1,0.3,0.7,0.9}
   {
    \draw [myarrow,b] (fx.south) -- ($(b1.north west)!\x!(b1.north east)$);
    \draw [myarrow,b] ($(b1.south west)!0.1!(b1.south east)$) -- ($(b2.north west)!\x!(b2.north east)$);

    \ifnum \i=3
      % don't do anything for third one
    \else
      \draw [myarrow,r] ($(b1.north west)!\x!(b1.north east)$) -- ($(r2.south west)!\x!(r2.south east)$);
      \draw [myarrow,r] ($(b2.north west)!\x!(b2.north east)$) -- ($(r3.south west)!\x!(r3.south east)$);
    \fi
   }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! Maybe I can try like this.